# How to hover border using css and html?

Tags: css

how I can achieve this same result with on hover, dotted border for each item in the list. Try it yourself by hovering the packages.

https://www.bitrix24.com/prices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple,
Try

```
tr:hover{
    outline: thin dashed;
}
```

Working Example:

Link https://codepen.io/vikas_saini/pen/poogeWx

Comment: That's pretty awesome! Thanks Vikas! How would I make the transition a smoother effect though from one to the other?

Comment: Well you can use transition property, its available in the Example i provided.
I have also updated the animation in the example so you can directly view.

Comment: Example Animation effect is "Ghost Trail effect"

Answer (score -1):

you can use this particular div. if you need these attraction

**very easiest css :**

```
tr:hover {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px dotted #68ddff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

i think good working for you.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
#mytable tr.row:hover td
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
#mytable tr.row:hover td
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
  
tr{
   transition: outline 1s;
   outline: thin solid;
   outline-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="mytable">
  <tr class="row">
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Foram for the help!